# Create a foreach-loop on search and replace

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, addition

I currently have a script for my WordPress site that finds a `<h3>`-tag and adds an `id` to it

```
<?php 
    $phrase = get_the_content();
    $phrase = apply_filters('the_content', $phrase);
    $replace = '<h3 id="thetag">';

    echo str_replace('<h3>', $replace, $phrase);
?>
```

I would like to add an `id="$i++"` to every `<h3>` tag.

I thought about this but that gives me an foreach error:

```
<?php 
    $phrase = get_the_content();
    $phrase = apply_filters('the_content', $phrase);
    $tag='<h3>';
    $i=0;
    foreach ($tag as $replace){
        $replace = '<h3 id="'.$i++.'">';
        echo str_replace($tag, $replace, $phrase);
    }
?>
```

Error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...`

Any ideas?
M.

Comment: $i=o; <- I don't think this is a zero (0)

Comment: A foreach loop on a string is not going to happen. You should first find a method which crawls your content. And then use a foreach on the response of that method.

Comment: @Michal-sk웃 Thnx. I'll try to that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In str_replace function third parameter is an output variable to check how many replacements were performed. Use preg_replace function:

```
<?php 
    $phrase = get_the_content();
    $phrase = apply_filters('the_content', $phrase);
    $tag='<h3>';
    $i=0;
    $c = substr_count($phrase, $tag);
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
        $replace = '<h3 id="'.$i.'">';
        $phrase = preg_replace('/'.$tag.'/', $replace, $phrase, 1);
    }
    echo $phrase;   
?>
```

Comment: is this line: echo preg_replace($tag, $replace, $phrase, 1); we have to replace $phrase string with new value. please use this: $phrase = preg_replace($tag, $replace, $phrase, 1); echo $phrase;

Comment: Nice. However this only applies to the first `<h3>`. Something went wrong I guess because there are some lost > and < tags. "<>This is a H3 title". FireBug gives me this: <
<h3 id="0">>This is a H3 title</h3>
<p>
<p>
<h3>This is another</h3>

Comment: Same result. Can you explain what the "1" does in the preg_replace();?

Comment: third parameter in preg_replace defines how many <h3> will replace with new value.

Comment: Thnx. I tried to put on errors but no errors :-( BTW it repeats the content of the page 6 times.....? and everytime the content reloads the $i++ adds 1

Comment: please check again, i tested and edited the code. it works correctly.

Comment: It runs but the $i++ doesn't run :-)

Comment: test again :) I had forgotten ", 1" in preg_replace function.

Comment: You... my friend are superb. Thank you so much...!

Answer (score 0):

You first nee to get an array of all  tags, you do a foreach on a string.

```
foreach(array("<h3>","<h3>") as $replace){
...
}
```

I don't tested this but this will help your way out. :-)

Regards.

Comment: Yeah but then I first need a loop to do that because I never know how many `<h3>` there will be\